# Imagen with 0 bytes in Firebase-storage upload from Node js

Tags: node.js, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I'm trying to upload an image to Firebase-storage from Node.js,
I followed the follow that gives firebase in their doc and all run fine but when the image is in the storage the size is 0 bytes and you can not see the preview.

This is my code:

```
const uploadImageToStorage = (file,filename) => {
    let prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!file) {
            reject('No image file');
        }
        let newFileName = `${file.originalname}_${Date.now()}`;
        let fileUpload = bucket.file(newFileName);
        const blobStream = fileUpload.createWriteStream({
            metadata: {
                contentType: file.mimetype
            }
        });

        blobStream.on('error', (error) => {
            reject('Something is wrong! Unable to upload at the moment.');
        });

        blobStream.on('finish', () => {
            // The public URL can be used to directly access the file via HTTP.
            const url = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${fileUpload.name}`;
            resolve(url);
        });

        blobStream.end(file.buffer);
    });
    return prom;
}
```

This is my app.post method:

```
app.post('/Upload_img',multer.single("file"), function (req, res) {

    console.log("Upload Imagennes");
    let url = "";
    let file= req.file;
    if (file) {
        uploadImageToStorage(file,file.name).then((success) => {
            url = success;
            res.status(200).send(url);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }



}
```

The Storage:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to upload a png file using your `uploadImageToStorage` function. I was calling it directly, without using `multer`:

```
(async () => {
  const buffer = fs.readFileSync('./android.png');
  const file = {
    originalname: 'android.png',
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    buffer,
  }
  try {
    return await uploadImageToStorage(file, file.originalname);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

This works as expected. So the problem is probably in your Express.js code or in multer. Try logging `req.file` and `req.file.buffer` in the server code, and see it has the expected data.